# Parsing simple sip messages with XPath on android

Tags: android, xpath

I am trying to parse simple SIP messages using XPath and Android. One of this messages is described in [this document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-simple-iscomposing-03).

The actual message looks like this:

```
<isComposing xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:imiscomposing'
             xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <state>active </state>
    <contenttype> text/html </contenttype>
    <refresh>60</refresh>
</isComposing>
```

I have this block of code that get the message from the SIP request and tries to parse it in order to find the state,

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false); // never forget this! THIS WAS TRUE ORIGINALLY CHANGED BY MAXSAP
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Log.e("IMHandler","<onTransRequest> parsing body:: "+ req.getBody());
        Document doc = builder.parse(req.getBody());

        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("//isComposing/state/text()");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Log.e("IMHandler"," <onTransRequest>  *************** PARSING ***********");
            Log.e("IMHandler"," <onTransRequest>  NodeValue"+nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            Log.e("IMHandler"," <onTransRequest>  *************** /PARSING ***********");
        }
    
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but in this line  builder.parse(req.getBody()); I am getting the error:

```
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: <SPAN STYLE="FONT-FAMILY:Arial; FONT-SIZE:10pt ">dfg</SPAN>
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:275)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:159)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:120)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:158)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.IMHandler.onTransRequest(IMHandler.java:239)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.zoolu.sip.transaction.TransactionServer.onReceivedMessage(TransactionServer.java:148)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.zoolu.sip.provider.SipProvider.processReceivedMessage(SipProvider.java:1091)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.zoolu.sip.provider.SipProvider.onReceivedMessage(SipProvider.java:1203)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.zoolu.sip.provider.UdpTransport.onReceivedPacket(UdpTransport.java:117)
03-20 20:03:44.637: WARN/System.err(4150):     at org.zoolu.net.UdpProvider.run(UdpProvider.java:189)
```

Has anyone encountered the same error? I am new to using XPath, also note that I have changed the namespace awarnes to hoping that this was a name space problem but no luck.

Comment: I think the problem not in XPath. What is `req`? Show some code related to the `req` variable.

Comment: Req is mjsip Message object. Thid is an ontransaction request method and req is the sip message of that request. Regards maxsap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `req.getBody` is processed to create a stream (?) to parse, some URL interactions is taking place. Your code us using a malformed URL.

Twice check that the URL is used to create a `req` object is correctly formed one.

**EDIT:**

The method DocumentBuilder.parse(String) is parsing a document from a specified URL. Then, a `getBody()` method returning a `String` and `DocumentBuilder` trying to interprete it as a string URL. You need to use [parse(InputStream)](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29) or [parse(File)](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.io.File%29) in your case.

**EDIT:**
You need to specify namespace context for your XPath operation. Try to add these lines before evaluating an expression.

```
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
        public String getNamespaceURI(String s) {
            if (s.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX))
                return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
            else
                return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(s);
        }

        public String getPrefix(String s) {
            return doc.lookupPrefix(s);
        }

        public Iterator getPrefixes(String s) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Olegas, from what I understand you are saying that I am using getBody method while there some kind of processing is taking place correct? but this method returns a plain string what kind of processing is there?

Comment: @Olegas, thanks a lot, I have changed the getMessage method with this:  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.getBody().getBytes());   and works fine, know I have to find the correct XPath statement to correctly parse the document.

Comment: @maxsap and what is the problem with XPath now? Are you getting wrong result set?

Comment: @Olegas, I am getting a NodeList that contains 0 elements but the xml is as shown in the original message. I have changed the xpath compile expression to this:self::node()/child::state but also no luck :S . Shouldn't this //isComposing/state/text() expression give me the value of the state element? regards maxsap

Comment: @maxsap I've edited my answer. I think you need to add namespace context resolution to your query.